# PsPicture baseline

Tags: pstricks, baseline

When compiling the following MWE with LaTeX->PS->PDF, the `psframe` ist aligned correctly to the baseline. Using `auto-pst-pdf` and `PDFLaTeX`, I get the following unwanted gaps. `pst-pdf` doesn't work either.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
Baseline\rule{10mm}{1pt}%
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,3)
\psframe(0,0)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}%
\rule{10mm}{1pt}Baseline
\end{document}
```

**Question 1:**
Is it just a problem of `auto-pst-pdf`? Sure, `XeLaTeX` *is* solution for this problem, but I'd prefer to stick to `PDFLaTeX` and `auto-pst-pdf`.
**Question 2:** Does it make a difference whether using `pst-pdf' or`auto-pst-pdf`(as`auto-pst-pdf`loads`pst-pdf` internally?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: You can use `\psset{dimen=inner}`  as a work-around:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

Baseline\rule{10mm}{1pt}%
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,3)
\begin{postscript}%
\psset{dimen=inner}
\psframe(0,0)(4,3)
\end{postscript}%
\end{pspicture}%
\rule{10mm}{1pt}Baseline

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the need of `\begin{postscript}`? All images worked without this before ...

Comment: It's an environment required by auto-pst-pdf. Perhaps it is useful for more complex pictures.

Comment: Environment `postscript` is only needed when there is _no_ environment `pspicture`!

Comment: @Herbert: I misunderstood. I thought auto-pst-pdf preferred `postscript`. Thank you for the point!